# How to input data in d3.js AreaChart And what need to code to achieve one chart and individual tootip info

Tags: charts, d3.js

I am trying to implement D3.js charts and using nvd3.js examples for it, I want to show two data set in one area(Means Want to Draw Chart for Sum of Facebook and Twitter positive sentiments with respect to time, in one area chart with respect to time). And want to show one tooltip which shows indvidual contribution of facebook and twiiter and total, As you can see in Attached image. I have done only for facebook or twiter not for both in one chart.

Q: How to input data in d3.js AreaChart And what need to code to achieve these results. 
Good Answer will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Expected Result Image.
http://hudld.com/tidylab/testing.html

Comment: Need A Expert D3.js charts developer help. If question is not clear ask me. I will explain it more...

Comment: There are [many examples](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883195) also with [multiple data](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885211). You should look through them and try to archive what you want. For the mouse interactivity, there is the [on](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-on) that lets you attach listeners.

Comment: DrColossos Thanks for this, but i am confuse how to input data for example i have data is values{ date:"2/1/2013", sentiments: ["facebook":6 , twitter:7, total: 13],date:"2/1/2013", ["facebook":5 , twitter:4, total: 9],date:"8/1/2013" sentiments: ["facebook":50 , twitter:55, total: 110]} How can i achieve chart with date at x-axis and total at y-axis, And I can get value of facebook and twitter for each date for showing tooltip as shown in image.http://hudld.com/tidylab/testing.html

Comment: var chartsdata = [
        { 
            "key" : "Facebook Positive" , 
            "values" : [ [ 1138683600000 ,25,12, 13] , [   1141102800000 , 30, 16, 14] , [ 1143781200000 , 20, 10 ,10]  } Question is here in values first is Date means X-axis, Second is Y-axis and i can get them easily. but how can i get third and fourth value, In examples only two values are specified.. any code help to get third and fourth value for specific date using d3.js.